# How to add new ornaments to psvectorian?

Tags: pstricks, package-writing, pgfornament, psvectorian

I've been using the package pst-vectorian (https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-vectorian) in order to customise part, chapter and section headings. I, however, would like to add new ornaments by using other vector graphic files (usually, an .eps file extension).

It seems that the ornaments contained in pst-vectorian come from the freely available ones in https://www.vectorian.net/free-vintage-vectors.html .

I would like to add, for instance, also other ornaments of https://www.vectorian.net which are not contained in this freely available package. I suppose, however, that I can't post here these ornaments since they are not free (it's easy to find online, though). These files are in the format .ai and .eps.

In order to have a concrete example, if necessary, I will suggest using , for instance, the ornaments available here https://www.freepik.com/free-photos-vectors/floral-ornaments .

To be honest, I don't even know how to start as I don't understand the content of the pst-vectorian package nor how a package works in general.

I'm not really familiar with the pgfornament package. However, if it's easier, I would be happy with an answer dealing with this package instead of the former one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For those who voted for close: The question is absolutely not "too broad"!

Comment: @Red-Cloud Please refrain from using exclamation marks when addressing other users!

Comment: @marmot: Please also refrain from using exclamation marks when addressing other users!

Comment: @Gold Digging Programmer: Please also refrain from using exclamation marks when addressing other users!

Answer (score 5):

It does not make real sense to extend the `psvectorian` package. It is much more easier to use a single graphic file.

However, if you really want it, then copy the files `psvectorian.tex` and `psvectorian.pro` into your local directory as `psvectorian2.tex` and `psvectorian2.pro`. For a test you can save the file in the documents directory.
In the style file replace

```
\ProvidesPackage{psvectorian}[2012/12/12 v0.4 vector ornaments]
\pstheader{psvectorian.pro}%
```

by

```
\ProvidesPackage{psvectorian2}[2012/12/12 v0.4 vector ornaments]
\pstheader{psvectorian2.pro}%
```

If you have a single ornament as `eps` file then you can extend the two files: Into `psvectorian2.sty` extend the `\ifcase` wit the next number which is ornament 197 and insert the values for the `pspicture` environment.
Into the `psvectorian2.pro` you have to include the PostScript code from the `eps`file.

Often it is easier to convert a raster image file into a vector format, then the code is shorter as images created by Illustrator or something else. Here is an example where I first converted the `jpg` image into a `pnm` format and then used `potrace` as

```
 potrace -b ps -c myImage.pnm
```

It creates a PostScript file which code I inserted into the `pro` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psvectorian2}

\begin{document}
  \psvectorian{197}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not understanding some points though 1) By using a single graphic file, do you mean something like graphicx? If so, why psvectorian was written in this way instead of simply adding the eps file through graphicx? 

2) What's the value for the pspicture environment? I don't get exactly what this means. For the 196, the line is \or\def\@psvectorianX{148}\def\@psvectorianY{30}%196, but I don't get how it should be for the next ornament .

3) From where do I start to copy the ps code? More precisely, 
/vec197 {
1 setlinejoin
%\pst@setColor
newpath
[what here?]

Comment: The ps code starts with something like: /languagelevel where
{ pop languagelevel } { 1 } ifelse
2 lt { /Helvetica findfont 12 scalefont setfont 50 500 moveto
  (This print job requires a PostScript Language Level 2 printer.) show
  showpage quit } if [...]

Comment: Then a lot of lines down it starts to show some numbers: %%EndPageSetup
q 0 -1 52 80 rectclip q
0.309804 0.298039 0.298039 rg [...]

Comment: Yes, using `\includegraphics` from `graphics` is easier. If you have something like `0.298039 0.298039 rg`  in your code, then it was converted from PDF and makes things complicated. `psvectorian` uses pure PostScript code without all those helper commands defined by `pdftops`. Run `kpsewhich psvectorian.pro` and you'll get the location of the PostScript prologue file. It shows you how the single ornaments are defined.